# Method for creating binary numbers in matrix

Tags: java, matrix, binary, numbers

I'm creating a method in Java that given an integer x creates a matrix of 2^x rows and x columns in which each array rapresents a binary number.

Ex: x = 4

matrix =

- 0 0 0 0
- 0 0 0 1
- 0 0 1 0
- 0 0 1 1
- 0 1 0 0

etc.

```
public static int[][] routes(int b) {
    int[][] r = new int[(int)Math.pow(2,b)][b];
    int i = 1;
    while (i < r.length) {
        r[i] = r[i-1];
        int h = 1;
        while (r[i][b-h] == 1) {
            h += 1;
        }
        r[i][b-h] = 1;
        h -= 1;
        while (h >= 1) {
            r[i][b-h] = 0;
            h -= 1;
        }
        i += 1;
    }
    return r;
}
```

That's the method. It does return a matrix full of 1 however, and I can't see the bug.

Answer (score 2):

Try this code:

```
public static int[][] routes(int b) {
    int[][] r = new int[(int)Math.pow(2,b)][b];

    for(int i = 0 ; i < r.length; ++i){
        for( int j = 0 ; j < r[0].length; ++j){
            r[i][j]=0;
        }
    }

    for(int i = 1; i < r.length ; ++i){
        int j = b-1;

            while( r[i-1][j] == 1 ){
                r[i][j] = 0;
                j--;
            }
            r[i][j] = 1;
            for( j-- ; j >= 0 ; j--){
                r[i][j] = r[i-1][j];
            }
    }
    return r;
}
```

Comment: Thanks to everybody!

Answer (score 0):

You can use Java's built-in ability to represent integers as binary numbers by scanning the bits using the `x & (1<pos)` trick:

```
while (i < r.length) {
    for (int pos = 0 ; pos != b ; pos++) {
        r[i][pos] = (i & (1 << pos)) != 0 ? 1 : 0;
    }
}
```

That is all you need, really: binary representation of `i`, the index of the row, corresponds to bits of the binary number that you want to produce.

Comment: Yeah, I know but I wanted to try the method of looking for 0 and 1 in the previous number.

Comment: @RandomDev Then `h` has to start at zero, and always go up, not up then down.

Answer (score 0):

You mistake is with your `r[i] = r[i-1]`. It does not copy the row, it makes the row point to *the same array* as the previous row. From then on you are just editing the same row over again.